# Communication between android studio and Java server. Problem GRPC

Tags: java, android, grpc

I need to setup a communication between an android studio app and a java server,
I tried XMLRPC but it did not work,
I am trying GRPC at the moment but a dont understand how to generate the code from the proto file on android studio.

this is my code on the server side,

```java
public class HelloWorldServer extends HelloServiceGrpc.HelloServiceImplBase {

    @Override
    public void hello( HelloRequest request, StreamObserver<HelloResponse> responseObserver){
        String greeting = new StringBuilder()
                .append("Hello, ")
                .append(request.getFirstName())
                .append(" ")
                .append(request.getLastName())
                .toString();

        HelloResponse response = HelloResponse.newBuilder()
                .setGreeting(greeting)
                .build();

        responseObserver.onNext(response);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [hello world example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.32.2/examples/android/helloworld/build.gradle) in the gRPC repository, the codge generation is done by the [protobuf-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

...

protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.12.0' }
    plugins {
        grpc { 
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.34.0-SNAPSHOT' // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java { option 'lite' }
            }
            task.plugins {
                grpc { // Options added to --grpc_out
                    option 'lite' 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the example, proto files are put in `src/main/proto`, which is the default place (or more formally, SourceDirectorySet) for source proto files that the plugin would pick up.

Applying the protobuf-gradle-plugin automatically adds gradle tasks to the build that generate code for you. The generated code will be fed to Java compilation by the plugin as well. So you basically do not need to do any thing manually. You can find more about how the plugin works in its [README](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/blob/master/README.md).